# Text on 'Save' button when editing duplicate list is wrongly aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, duplicate-questions

When editing the duplicate list (a tool for ♦ moderator and gold tag badge holders), the text on the 'Save' button is wrongly aligned:

[image]

Tested in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Catalina.

Comment: I'm going through bug reports and I think we may have already fixed this in some button refactors we've been doing. I'm unable to reproduce it, are you still able to? Thanks for the report!

Comment: @kristinalustig seems to be fixed, thanks!